# CUDA memory transfer issue

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am trying to execute a code which first transfers data from CPU to GPU memory and vice-versa. In spite of increasing the volume of data, the data transfer time remains the same
as if no data transfer is actually taking place. I am posting the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* Core input/output operations                         */
#include <stdlib.h> /* Conversions, random numbers, memory allocation, etc. */
#include <math.h>   /* Common mathematical functions                        */
#include <time.h>   /* Converting between various date/time formats         */
#include <cuda.h>   /* CUDA related stuff                                   */
#include <sys/time.h>
__global__ void device_volume(float *x_d,float *y_d)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
}

int main(void)
{
    float *x_h,*y_h,*x_d,*y_d,*z_h,*z_d;
    long long  size=9999999;
    long long nbytes=size*sizeof(float);

    timeval t1,t2;
    double et;

    x_h=(float*)malloc(nbytes);
    y_h=(float*)malloc(nbytes);

    z_h=(float*)malloc(nbytes);

    cudaMalloc((void **)&x_d,size*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&y_d,size*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&z_d,size*sizeof(float));
    gettimeofday(&t1,NULL);

    cudaMemcpy(x_d, x_h, nbytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(y_d, y_h, nbytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(z_d, z_h, nbytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    gettimeofday(&t2,NULL);
    et = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      // sec to ms
    et += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms
    printf("\n %ld\t\t%f\t\t",nbytes,et);
    et=0.0;
    //printf("%f %d\n",seconds,CLOCKS_PER_SEC); 

    // launch a kernel with a single thread to greet from the device
    //device_volume<<<1,1>>>(x_d,y_d);
    gettimeofday(&t1,NULL);

    cudaMemcpy(x_h, x_d, nbytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(y_h, y_d, nbytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(z_h, z_d, nbytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    gettimeofday(&t2,NULL);

    et = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      // sec to ms
    et += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms
    printf("%f\n",et);
    cudaFree(x_d);
    cudaFree(y_d);
    cudaFree(z_d); 
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I believe `cudaMemcpy` is asynchronous - you would need to run at least a dummy kernel before collecting the second time stamp.

Comment: Well, cudaMemcpy is synchronous and  cudaMemcpyAsync is the async variant. I have tested this code on a different C1050 tesla GPU and it worked just fine. But with a different GTX 250, it is not giving a proper result.

Comment: OK - by asynchronous I mean that the call returns as soon as the DMA transfer is initiated, so the transfer is not complete until some time later. Calling a kernel will then block until any pending DMA transfers are complete. Try adding a dummy kernel and see if it helps.

Comment: As an aside, you're better off using the cuda event API for timing cuda operations.  Some cuda operations are asynchronous, and can give puzzling timing results because they may transfer control back to the CPU thread almost immediately.  But for this case, my best guess is you should also do cuda error checking.  You may be not transferring any data at all because the GPU is not available for some reason.  I compiled and ran your code and got 28 and 76 for a size of 9999999, and when I changed size to 99999 I got 0.54 and 0.84.  If you want fastest transfer, investigate using cudaHostAlloc.

Comment: Paul R, No, cudaMemcpy() is *not* asynchronous.  It does not return until the memcpy has been completed. As the name implies, the asynchronous memcpy in CUDA is called cudaMemcpyAsync().  Note though that cudaMemcpyAsync() requires the host memory to be pinned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try cudaEvent for capturing the time for GPU code.
2. Try use the Visual profiler to see how much time is spend on the memcpy. The profiler will show all execution time spend on the GPU for every cuda related operations.

Answer (score 0):

It stays the same because it takes the same time. In your code you don't add up the transfer times.